# How to update value of a radio using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code for radios:

```
<input type='radio' name='a_27' value='Yes' id='a_27_0' />

<input type='radio' name='a_27' value='No' id='a_27_1' />
```

I'm trying to set the selected value of the radio using this code:

```
var field="a_" + this.id;
$('[name="' + field + '"]').val(this.value);
console.log("name is " + field + ", val is " + this.value);
```

However it doesn't work, nothing happens when this runs. Here's the output from Firebug's console which occurs after the 3rd line:

> name is a_27, val is Yes

Any ideas?

I would prefer a method which would also work on `<select>s`, so I wouldn't need to write additional/seperate code for radios and selects.

Edit: A weird problem I've noticed that although my html code gives a different value (yes/no), in firebug it shows both radios as having the value 'yes'. If I select no and click save, the javascript function still receives 'yes' instead of no. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit 2: The full function:

```
function processMultiOptAnswers()
{
    $.each(multiOpts,function()
        {
            var field="a_" + this.id;
            console.log("name is " + field + ", val is " + this.value);

            $('[name="' + field + '"]').val(this.value);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you add some extra detail, in particular the context your javascript is getting called in as it would help to be able to know exactly what 'this' is. I'm guessing it's an onclick?

Comment: It happens on $(document).ready()

Comment: $('[name="' + field + '"]').val(this.value);
That selects BOTH radios... Why would you want both radios to have the same value? Are you sure you mean to be working with the checked="checked" attribute because this makes no sense at the moment.

Also if it runs on document ready are you saying that 'this' = document??

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just figured now that by doing name= I'm accessing both radios. But without doing it and without knowing the id of the radio that I want to select, how can I set that radio to be selected? For example, if both values are unselected but I want to select the radio which says 'Yes', how can I select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your log should be if `this.value` is different.

```
$('[name="' + field + '"]').val(this.value);
console.log("name is " + field + ", val is " + $('[name="' + field + '"]').val());
```

To make it selected

```
$('[name="' + field + '"]').attr("checked", "checked");
```

I haven't tested this, but you might have to remove that attribute from the other ones.

Comment: Weird, that does give the new (changed) value but on the form itself the appropriate value isn't selected. Is there something wrong with my html code for creating the radios?

Comment: That made the radio get selected but its still showing the same value for all radios...

Comment: Your selector should use ID rather than the NAME to slect your radios as they ALL share the same name - you're updating all of them to the new value at once.

Comment: Is there no way to select the radio I want without knowing the id of the radio?

Comment: For example, if I wanted to select the radio saying 'No' but I didn't know the id of it, how can I select it? (Dan, I unchecked your answer because by using name=.. its updating values of both radios instead of selecting the one whose value is 'Yes'

Comment: Maybe what you can do is add a new radio item with the new value, then remove the ones with the value you want to replace.